# What does the Autoloads environment do?

Tags: r

The second-to-last item on the `search()` path is (always?) an environment called `Autoloads`.  All I could find about this topic is a sentence on page 26 of the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf) (pdf).

> An Autoloads environment is used for holding proxy objects that may be loaded on demand.

Please can you give me more of an explanation about what this is environment is used for.

Comment: Interesting question. It's mostly answered by reading `?autoload`, and running the example therein.

Comment: I don't feel knowledgeable enough to give an actual answer but `?Autoloads` and `example(autoload)` provide some decent info on what it is and what it is used for.

Comment: Josh O'Brien and Dason: Thanks for the tip.  I thought I's searched for that, but looking through my history I'd actually looked for `??autolaod`, which doesn't return anything useful.  I've drafted an answer based upon the help page; you may want to contribute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Autoloading provides a way of loading packages in the future, only at the point at which they are used (if at all).  So if a function from a package *may* soon be used, but (for memory reasons, perhaps) you don't want to load the package unless absolutely necessary, you can use the `autoload` function to promise to make a function available if it is used.

The `Autoloads` environment (accessible via `as.environment("Autoloads")` or `.AutoloadEnv`) stores the functions that it will promise to load and a character vector, `.Autoloaded`, that names the packages that need to be loaded.

Further information can be found in the [`?autoload`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Autoloads) help page and [R-FAQ 7.6](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-does-autoloading-work_003f).

Comment: I'm curious if anybody actually uses this thing.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think that this feature may have been useful in the 1990s when PCs were much less powerful and loading packages took up a non-trivial amount of memory.  I don't see much use for this now.