# Function reading many csv

Tags: r

I created a function that allows to assign csv into variables. However it's not working and I have no idea why. Here's the code:

```
 file_id <- readline("Type a common word for your files: ")
 file_list <- list.files(pattern = file_id)

 multi.csv <- function(pattern.seq)
  {
    for(i in 1:length(pattern.seq))
       {
          assign(pattern.seq[i], read.csv(pattern.seq[i]))
       }
  }

multi.csv(pattern.seq = file_list)

cat(" Now your .csv files are stored in variables: ", file_list)
```

Let me explain what's going on here. Lets assume that I have ten csv. files that differs only by a certain number in their names eg. file_01, file_02... Function list.files reckognizes the pattern in file names and stores it in the char vector c("file_02", "file_02"...). Then I wrote the function multi.csv that should assign the data stored in csv. into variables. However it's not working. What's more, when I call the `assign` function outside the multi.csv function with a certain element of file_list vector:

```
assign(file_list[1], read.csv(file_list[1]))
```

it works as it should: variable file_01 stores the data from file_01.csv.

Have you got any idea why it's not working inside multi.csv function?

I'm fully aware that the whole problem of reading many csv files can be solved differently but I want to know what's wrong here.

Comment: [Assign()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/assign) expects a sting literal in first argument. Do not use it to extend a list. Plus you are re-using the same variable without a return in function. Consider: `dfList <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but why do you need any pattern at all?  Can't you just loop through all files in a folder and merge the contents into one single dataset?  Try the script below and see if it gets you what you want.

```
setwd("C:/Users/xxx/")

file_list <- list.files()

file_list <- list.files("C:/Users/xxx/")

for (file in file_list){

  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is related to *scope*.

In R, every variable is stored in an environment.

- There is a global environment which stores "top-level" variables. This is sometimes called the workspace or workspace environment.
- There are package environments (actually two per package: one public and one private).
- You can create custom environments with [`new.env()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html).
- You can copy data.frames, lists, and existing [`save()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) files to new environments with [`attach()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attach.html), but this is discouraged.
- There are a few fairly obscure and usually unimportant environments, such as the empty environment and the [Autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401977/what-does-the-autoloads-environment-do) environment.
- Finally, a new environment is created for each evaluation of a function, which is referred to as the *evaluation environment* for that particular evaluation of that particular function.

The documentation on [`assign()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) is a bit scattered when it comes to communicating exactly *which* environment receives the variable-to-be-assigned, but I'll try to quote all the relevant passages:

> *pos*     where to do the assignment. By default, assigns into the current environment. See ‘Details’ for other possibilities.

---

> *envir*     the [environment](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html) to use. See ‘Details’.

---

> The *pos* argument can specify the environment in which to assign the object in any of several ways: as -1 (the default), as a positive integer (the position in the [search](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/search.html) list); as the character string name of an element in the search list; or as an [environment](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html) (including using [sys.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sys.parent.html) to access the currently active function calls). The *envir* argument is an alternative way to specify an environment, but is primarily for back compatibility.

---

> Note that assignment to an attached list or data frame changes the attached copy and not the original object: see [attach](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attach.html) and [with](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html).

---

> If no *envir* is specified, then the assignment takes place in the currently active environment.

---

> If *inherits* is TRUE, enclosing environments of the supplied environment are searched until the variable *x* is encountered. The value is then assigned in the environment in which the variable is encountered (provided that the binding is not locked: see [lockBinding](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bindenv.html): if it is, an error is signaled). If the symbol is not encountered then assignment takes place in the user's workspace (the global environment).
>
> If *inherits* is FALSE, assignment takes place in the initial frame of *envir*, unless an existing binding is locked or there is no existing binding and the environment is locked (when an error is signaled).

Because you have not specified any of the `pos`, `envir`, or `inherits` arguments in your `assign()` call, the variable ends up being assigned into the "current" aka "active" environment. Because the `assign()` call takes place inside of a call to your `multi.csv()` function, the "current" aka "active" environment is the evaluation environment of that particular evaluation of your `multi.csv()` function. When the evaluation of `multi.csv()` completes, the environment is destroyed, and the variable is destroyed with it (note: closuring an evaluation environment prevents it from being destroyed, but your code is not doing any closuring, so that doesn't apply here).

This also helps to explain why your top-level call to `assign()` works: because the "current" aka "active" environment in that case is the global environment, so the variable lands right where you expect it: in your workspace environment.

You can solve the problem by passing `pos=1L` or `envir=globalenv()` in your `assign()` call.

(You could also solve the problem by passing `inherits=T`, which is akin to using the superassignment operator [`<<-`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html), but this is discouraged.)

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659269/what-does-it-mean-by-formulas-and-closures-being-able-to-capture-the-enclosing/30664079#30664079) for more information.